# Typeahead bloodhound not working properly in nexus 5

Tags: typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead, twitter-typeahead, bloodhound

While typing the Search characters in input field, sometimes, it automatically clears the input field. We are facing this issue in only nexus 5, rest all devices are working fine with typeahead.bundle.js (0.10.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using keydown event or any other event related to the key events, that will not be supported on mobile. event.keyCode, event.charCode, event.which are all 0 for mobile phones. Therefore don't use any of such event handler. This may be causing problem in your typeahead typing.